# Assets problem uploading large files to Amazon S3

Tags: assets

I am having an issue with Assets when trying to upload large-ish .mp3 files to an Amazon S3 bucket.

Here is my setup:

- ExpressionEngine v2.5.5
- Assets v2.1.2
- PHP v5.4.10 (via MAMP)
- Dedicated Amazon bucket (tested with smaller image files and is confirmed to be working and accepting uploads)

I have adjusted my php.ini settings to the following values:

- `post_max_size = 500M`
- `upload_max_filesize = 500M`
- `max_execution_time = 600`
- `max_input_time = 600`
- `memory_limit = 128M`

While trying to upload a .mp3 file that is 120MB in size (it's a podcast), I get the following error in Assets:

> Could not upload the file - server returned an unexpected response. Please check the server settings.

Checking the PHP error log, this is the message I see:

> [05-May-2013 14:19:33 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 80987568 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

That's a lot of memory Assets is trying to use. I'm not sure how Assets deals with big files – does it try to load the entire contents in memory and then upload? Any other settings I could try?

A quick note – I did try uploading a 15MB .mp3 and that worked without problem.

Comment: Hey Chad - I've asked one of our engineers to look at this as such a large file will take some resources - I'm just not sure if what you're seeing is unexpectedly excessive.  I'll also try to locate a large MP3 of that sort and do some testing myself.  Thank you!

Comment: Hi Lisa – any chance the engineers have had a chance to look into this?

Comment: Hi Chad, my fault for not following up sooner, my apologies.  It looks like PHP may be dying before it reaches  Assets.  We may explore better ways of uploading for a future version of Assets; but for right now the immediate solution is to increase your memory to handle the larger sized uploads.

Comment: Hi Lisa. Okay, that is good to know. I'll try some different values and let you know what I find. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to attempt to use CORS -- http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/08/amazon-s3-cross-origin-resource-sharing.html

This will upload from the end user right to S3 -- it will perform faster.

Example code here: http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/1539/

Comment: CORS looks very interesting. This is something to look at in the future, but I am hoping there is a solution in place for Assets in lieu of writing a custom add-on.